# Monitoring file contents in Perl across rotations

Tags: perl, file

Good afternoon,

I have a small Perl script that essentially emulated the `tail -f` functionality on a Minecraft server.log.  The script checks for certain strings and acts in various ways.

A simplified version of the script is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $log = "PATH TO LOG";
my $curpos;

open(my $LOGFILE, $log) or die "Cannot open log file";

# SEEK TO EOF
seek($LOGFILE, 0, 2);

for (;;){
        my $line = undef;

        seek($LOGFILE,0,1);  ### clear OF condition
        for($curpos = tell($LOGFILE); <$LOGFILE>; $curpos = tell($LOGFILE)){
                $line = "$_ \n";


                if($line =~ /test string/i){
                        say "Found test string!";
                }
        }

        sleep 1;
        seek($LOGFILE,$curpos,0); ### Setting cursor at the EOF
}
```

When I had a test server up everything seemed to work fine.  In production, the server.log file gets rotated.  When a log gets rotated, the script keeps hold of original file, and not the file that replaces it.
I.e. server.log is being monitored, server.log gets moved and compressed to logs/date_x.log.gz, server.log is now a new file.

How can I adapt my script to monitor the filename "server.log", rather than the file that is currently called "server.log"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered just using `tail -F` as the input to your script:

```
tail -F server.log 2>/dev/null | perl -nE 'say if /match/'
```

This will watch the named file, passing each line to your script on STDIN. It will correctly track only server.log, as shown below:

```
echo 'match' >server.log
```

(matched by script)

```
mv server.log server.log.old
echo 'match' >server.log
```

(also matched)

You can open the `tail -F` as a file in Perl using:

```
open(my $fh, '-|', 'tail -F server.log 2>/dev/null') or die "$!\n";
```

Comment: Excellent, I hadn't known about the -F flag before, it's rather useful!
The script has been reworked and looks much cleaner now!

Answer (score 3):

You can check [inode numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for both, file name and file handle using [`stat()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html). If they differ, log file was rotated and file should be reopened for reading.

`$readline` is [iterator](http://www.perl.com/pub/2005/06/16/iterators.html) (obtained by `get_readline($file_name)`) which transparently takes care of such changes, and does "right thing".

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_readline {
  my ($fname) = @_;
  my $fh;

  return sub {
    my ($i1, $i2) = map { $_ ? (stat $_)[1] : 0 } $fh, $fname;

    if ($i1 != $i2) {
      undef $fh;
      open $fh, "<", $fname or return;
    }
    # reset handle to current position
    seek($fh, 0, 1) or die $!;
    return wantarray ?  <$fh> : scalar <$fh>;
  };
}

`seq 11 > log_file`;
my $readline = get_readline("log_file");

print "[regular reading]\n";
print $readline->();
print "[any new content?]\n";
print $readline->();

`rm log_file; seq 11 > log_file`;
print "[reading after log rotate]\n";
print $readline->();
```

output

```
[regular reading]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
[any new content?]
[reading after log rotate]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```